# Bunny::TCPConnectionFailed while running RabbitMQ examples from http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-ruby.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq, message-queue, chef-infra

I am getting the following error while trying to run RabbitMQ examples from http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-ruby.html. I understand the error occurs when connection to the host has failed. I definitely have RabbitMQ installed and also have Bunny installed. How can I reconfigure RaabitMQ to make this error go away? I am currently using default RabbitMQ configuration settings from the RabbitMQ installation. I see a few posts on this but no real answers.

[image: RabbitMQ-Bunny error]

Comment: you might as well need to post what configurations you attempted that failed, I do not have domain knowledge, but I guess that would help those who do.

Comment: It'd be great if you actually posted the text, rather than a screenshot of your terminal.

Comment: How is this Chef related? What cookbook(s) are you using?

Comment: Chef is related because when I tried the tests on a machine that had ruby from the ruby website rather than from the opscode installation, they work. But it doesnt work on the machine which has chef installed as from the call stack of the error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been a bunny bug. I tried versions 1.1.0 and 1.1.2 and I was facing this error. But installing 1.1.3 this morning seems have made this error go away. I am assuming a fix for chef compatibility went into this version.